# How to convert ISO date string into Zullu format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have below date time string which I am reading from an excel sheet

```
date_created = 2019-02-28 23:10:17.0000000 +11:00
```

How can I convert it into zullu format so that it looks like

```
date_created = 2019-02-28T23:10:17Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `string` methods.

**Ex:**

```
date_created = "2019-02-28 23:10:17.0000000 +11:00"
print(date_created.split(".")[0].replace(" ", "T") + "Z")
```

---

Or using `datetime`

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_created.split(".")[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

**Output:**

```
2019-02-28T23:10:17Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it as a date then export it into ISO format and append the `Z`:

```
import dateutil.parser

date_created = dateutil.parser.parse("2019-02-28 23:10:17.0000000 +11:00")
print(date_created.isoformat() + 'Z')
```